# C Variable arguments passing to function

Tags: c, parameters

I have a module with a a variable number of parameters:

```
int myprintf( const char *format, ...  ){

}
```

I want to declare a local char array, pass the "myprint" parameters to sprintf() so that sprintf() converts the parameters to a character array then I can do something with that character array.
By doing this, I do not have to re-invent the internals of sprintf.

In theory:

```
int myprintf( const char *format, ...  )

{
    char buf[ 512 ];

    sprintf( buf, format, ... );

  // now do something with buf

}
```

I am sure `va_start( a, b)`, `va_arg( c, d )` will have something to do with it; but va_arg seems to need parse the original argument list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: If I'm right, you're looking for [`vsnprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf).

Comment: @user3346861: there is no such language as "C/C++". good advice for this question differs greatly depending on the language.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on what Chris said, something like:

```
int vmyprintf(const char* format, va_list args)
{
        char buf[512];

        vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, args);
        // now do something with buf 
}

int myprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        int ret;

        va_start(args, format);
        ret = vmyprintf(format, args);
        va_end(args);
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: This. Any variadic function should be wrapping a `va_list` function so that others can wrap it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
void myprintf( const char *format, ...  )
{
    char buf[ 512 ];

    va_list vl;
    va_start (vl, format);
    vsnprintf(buf, 511, format, vl);
    va_end(vl);

    // now do something with buf
}
```

[Some other information is available in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688942/variable-arguments-in-c-how-to-get-values-with-a-generic-type/1689228#1689228)

Of course the above answer leave many issues open, for instance how will we handle buffer overflows or such. But this is another story.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to be it!